# jquery validate: how can I make a field validate on change?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

On jquery's validate plugin, an error message only disappears after the user has made focus on another element. I want to make it disappear as soon as the right info is written. How can validation be triggered 'onchange'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onkeyup: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I googled this. The setting was messing up with the defaults.

Comment: [Please read the docs for `onkeyup`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup):  *"A boolean `true` is **not** a valid value."* ~ since `onkeyup` is already the default behavior built into the plugin, you can only use the `onkeyup` option to disable or override the default function; setting it to `true` might break it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking into a similar problem. I believe the accepted answer is a little misleading. The `validate()` method is for initializing and setting up validation behavior, whereas the `valid()` method will actually run the validation check. So, in order to run a validation check on change, I ended up using something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#elementId").on("change", function() {
        $(this).valid();
    });
});
```